# Access Denied applying BGInfo64.exe in MDT

Tags: access-denied, mdt

I'm attempting to call BGInfo64.exe after the "Gather local only" step in the first group of my Task Sequence. However I'm getting access denials. I tried messing with NTFS permissions by allowing "Everyone" full access to see if that would help. But that did not work. It seems to be beyond user permissions. Has anyone encountered this problem that can lend some advice? The TS runs as it should otherwise.

The Step in my Task Sequence runs a command line:

```
\\<serverFQDN>\E$\DeploymentShare\Tools\x64\BGInfo64.exe \\<serverFQDN>\E$\DeploymentShare\Tools\x64\Stage01.bgi /nolicprompt /silent /timer:0
```

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up copying BGInfo64.exe, it's config file (.bgi), and the background the .bgi requires, to a directory in the winPE's wim. Before copying I also edited the .bgi to pull its wallpaper from the same directory using ".\wallpaper.bmp". Then I adjusted the command line in the TS to:

```
X:\Deploy\Tools\x64\BGInfo64.exe X:\Deploy\Tools\x64\Stage01.bgi /nolicprompt /silent /timer:0
```

By pulling the bginfo straight from the wim I bypass any network share issues. Not sure why this particular file had this problem however.